# Where can I find the PHPIniDir directive and its value in XAMPP installation setup on Windows 10 operating system?

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, php-ini

I'm using **Windows 10 Home Single Language** edition which is a **64-bit Operating  System**.

I've installed the Apache, PHP, MySQL using the latest copy of XAMPP on this machine.

I read the following sentence in the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file) :

> **php.ini** is searched for in these locations (in order):
>
> - SAPI module specific location (*PHPIniDir* directive in Apache 2, *-c* command line option in CGI and CLI, *php_ini* parameter in NSAPI,
>     *PHP_INI_PATH* environment variable in THTTPD)

Everything is installed properly on my machine. I checked the output of `phpinfo();` in my browser but I couldn't find out the *PHPIniDir* directive and its value anywhere in it.

So, please let me know where I can find the *PHPIniDir* directive and its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the `httpd-xampp.conf` (Apache configuration file), for example:

```
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

The `httpd-xampp.conf` file is in your `apache` installation folder, if you use xampp: `xampp\apache\conf\extra`.

**Update:**

As OP pointed out xampp contains it in:

> In `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf` file from line no. 39 to 41:
>
> `<IfModule php7_module> PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php" </IfModule>`

Comment: How should I check location of file 'httpd.conf' in the output of phpinfo() which is displayed in a web browser?

Comment: It should display the default configuration files

Comment: Correction : I've found the apache configuration file at location 'C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf' Please correct your answer accordingly.

Comment: @ Tamas Szoke : The output of phpinfo(); displayed in a web browser doesn't contain a thing like 'httpd-xampp.conf'. So, do you think that your answer should get modified accordingly?